# How to leverage a ViewModel in a MVVM light architecture in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.android

So I've tried going through a lot of tutorials about MVVM light and Xamarin NATIVE Android PCL projects

But I couldn't figure out how the architecture works, or why do we implement it

I'm sharing a small code structure based on MVVM, please if possible could someone tell me how would we be able to leverage a `ViewModel` in this scenario, let's say I need this for a `RecyclerView`

My Interface

```
public interface ITest
{
    Task<string> GetDataAsync();
}
```

And a Service,at least that is what i've understood

```
public class UserService : ITest
{
    // makes a call to a web api to get a user
    public async Task<string> GetDataAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://mywebapi.mydomain/api/currentuser");
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
           return content; 
           //return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(content);
        }
    }
}
```

Now lets I have a recycler view, and I need to create a `viewmodel` I suppose and leverage the above things into that and use it in my `recyclerview`
Any idea as to how should I proceed with this and also the approach so far I've taken is it correct?
Any inputs would be helpful

Comment: Did you try and create a view model and view yet?  What issues did you run into?

Comment: @KenTucker I don't know how to create a view model,i tried following some tutorials but im kinda confused